Wine Error: ntlm_auth was not found after Debian update?
I recently did a mundane update/upgrade:
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade

and later tried running a win program that i usually run on a daily basis with no problem, until now (foobar2000) and the program opens, works for a few seconds, then crashes and gives me the following error:
err:winediag:SECUR32_initNTLMSP ntlm_auth was not found or is outdated. Make sure that ntlm_auth >= 3.0.25 is in your path. Usually, you can find it in the winbind package of your distribution.

So I checked the version:
user@media:~/.wine/drive_c/Program Files$ ntlm_auth --version
Version 4.17.12-Debian

and the path:
user@media:~/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/foobar2000$ which ntlm_auth
/usr/bin/ntlm_auth

user@media:~/.wine/drive_c/Program Files$ echo $PATH
/home/user/.local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games

So I am not sure where else to go from here? There didnt seem to be many relevant posts related to this, but perhaps I missed something?

thoughts? Please?
